# Exception handling in django import-export

Tags: django, exception, django-import-export

A quick question about django import-export. Suppose I have a model like the one in the [docs](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), but with some additional constraints (note the Meta class):

```
    class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('Book name', max_length=100)
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=True, null=True)
        author_email = models.EmailField('Author email', max_length=75, blank=True)
        imported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        published = models.DateField('Published', blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
        categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

        class Meta:
            unique_together = ('name', 'author')
```

On bulk upload, I would ideally like that any rows containing errors (duplicate entries in this case -- but could be other type of "corrupt" rows too) to be skipped and the rest of the upload to continue. The corrupt rows should be logged into a file containing the row(s) in question and an additional column with the exception name.

There is a generic exceptions.py file :

```
class ImportExportError(Exception):
    """A generic exception for all others to extend."""
    pass


class FieldError(ImportExportError):
    """Raised when a field encounters an error."""
    pass
```

But it is not clear how to deal with the row by row situation and skipping. Any help from anyone who's dealt with this would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

[documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_workflow.html#import_data) is pretty clear:

> dry_run is a Boolean which determines if changes to the database are
>   made or if the import is only simulated. It defaults to False.
>
> raise_errors is a Boolean. If True, import should raise errors. The
>   default is False, which means that eventual errors and traceback will
>   be saved in Result instance.